# Referencing a Dot Net Standard Project in Dot Net Framework

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-4.8

Its been a while since I've used Dot Net Framework, so bare with me (been using Dot Net Core and now Net5.0).

So here is my scenario:

1. Library_A (Standard 2.0) which contains a class called "PersonEntity".
2. Library_B (Standard 2.0), this references the Library_A project.
3. ConsoleUI1 (Net5.0) this references Library_B only.
4. ConsoleUI2 (NetFramework4.8) this references Library_B only.

Now here is the issue:

- In ConsoleUI1, I am able to use "PersonEntity".
- In ConsoleU2, I cannot use "PersonEntity".

Why can't ConsoleUI2 use "PersonEntity"? Is there something I'm forgetting about .Net Framework?

Comment: You'll need to reference Library_A from your ConsoleUI2 for being able to reference PersonEntity.

Comment: And why is that in Dot Net Framework vs Dot Net Core?

Comment: .Net Core takes dependcies from libraries indirectly. Full-fat framework needs to know about all the dependencies direclty, even if these dependencies are "grand-child" dependencies.

Comment: Wow, .Net Core has become so nice to use that you take some things for granted. Appreciate your time to comment on this simple question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @trailmax in the comments,
".Net Core takes dependcies from libraries indirectly. Full-fat framework needs to know about all the dependencies direclty, even if these dependencies are "grand-child" dependencies"
"You'll need to reference Library_A from your ConsoleUI2 for being able to reference PersonEntity"

.Net Core has become so nice to use that many of what it offers is taken for granted compared to .Net Framework.

Comment: Here is some light reading on the topic: https://www.erikheemskerk.nl/transitive-nuget-dependencies-net-core-got-your-back/